# Xcode Git issues with Google Drive/Dropbox

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, git

Apparently XCode should recognize a git repo automatically, but after doing git init and my initial commit, XCode is not seeing the repo. I have my entire project and git repo in Google Drive, and I suspect that is causing some issue? What do I have to do to get XCode to read .git files in Google Drive?

**EDIT**

I tried doing a git init, add and commit to a project in my local drive and XCode still didn't recognize the git store, so this may not be a G Drive/Dropbox issue.

Comment: I don't know why Xcode is doing that, but putting your .git files in something like Dropbox or Google Drive seems likely to cause lots of problems in other ways. Why not just use git itself to share the code across computers?

Comment: there are some computers i use only temporarily so I'd like to work directly off Dropbox or G. Drive

Comment: Are you sure this is Google Drive-specific? Does Xcode recognize the git repo if it's outside of Google Drive?

Comment: hmm.. you're right. I just did git init, add, commit to a project in my local store and XCode is still not allowing me to do source control. thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. If this is a fresh project, you could just allow Xcode to create the git repo in the first place when you create the Xcode Project file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't put a Git repo on Dropbox or Google Drive. It is terrible. Dropbox, on sync, can scramble all git's internal files and screw it up your whole repository.

Instead, use a Git service. For something private, I recommend [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org).

Exemplifying:

Imagine you put your main repository on Dropbox. You sync your dropbox in another computer and pushes to it. The connection drops from that computer. You go to other computer, make another commit and pushes into the main repository. Everything goes fine.

Dropbox starts to sync in this computer. At the same time, the other computer starts to sync, too. But internally, there are lots of different files on the repo. How Dropbox knows how to keep and organize these files?

Simple answer: it doesn't. It will damage your repository, and that's nothing you can do about it. And this is not some kind of "it will almost never happen". It will happen, very soon.

And about the real question:

I never used Xcode, but I had similar issues with Eclipse. It's simple, though: Xcode does not know about the repo because you did not tell him that is a repo. To see how to do that on Xcode, you could see [here](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/95580-setting-up-git-with-xcode-4).

Comment: I can't improve on this answer, but there are also other repos out there too that are free that will save you from having to use Dropbox or G Drive. I'm a fan of ProjectLocker and Beanstalk as well. Github is free too if you don't mind your work being public.

Comment: If you know Git well enough, Dropbox does not cause any serious damage: conflicts only happen in refs and other aux files, which are trivial to fix manually; the object database stays intact. *Of course* you need to also use GitHub or BitBucket; however, storing the cloned repo on Dropbox is a great idea, esp combined with their unlimited undo history: any file you have ever saved is accessible forever, from anywhere, even if you forgot to commit it. (And if you share working folders within your team, you can see what everyone else is doing real-time.)